# Doctrine2 deletes entity when removing ManyToOne Relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my setup I have a simple OneToMany relation without cascading or orphan removal.

```
class Position {

/**
 * @var \Vorgaenge\Basis\DBBundle\Entity\Vorgang
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Vorgaenge\Basis\DBBundle\Entity\Vorgang", inversedBy="Positionen")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="VID", referencedColumnName="VID")
 */
protected $Vorgang;
}

class Vorgang {

/**
 * @var \Vorgaenge\Basis\DBBundle\Entity\Position
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Vorgaenge\Basis\DBBundle\Entity\Position", mappedBy="Vorgang")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"PID" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $Positionen;
}
```

All I do in my unittest is creating related entities ....

```
$entity = new \Vorgaenge\Basis\DBBundle\Entity\Vorgang();

$pos = new \Vorgaenge\Basis\DBBundle\Entity\Position();
$pos->Vorgang = $entity;

$pos2 = new \Vorgaenge\Basis\DBBundle\Entity\Position();
$pos2->Vorgang = $entity;

$em->persist($entity);
$em->persist($pos);
$em->persist($pos2);
$em->flush($entity);
```

.... and removing one of the relations after all entities an relations have been saved.

```
$pos->Vorgang = NULL;
$em->flush();
```

But somehow Doctrine deletes the entire entity $pos instead of only removing the relation by setting VID to 0.

I checked Doctrine's UnitOfWork doRemove and scheduleForDelete methods, but none of them seems to be involved.

Can anyone help me to understand why the Position entity is deleted and what needs to be done to prevent this?

Comment: This seems to be more like `@OneToOne` relationship. In any of `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne` one side of a relationshop is a `Collection` instance which does seem to be your case.

Comment: The question is not about @OneToOne just because she sets the relation from owning side.

Comment: It is OneToMany. 1 Vorgang has many Position. Vorgang::Positionen is the collection. I have not explicitely set this side of the relation because Doctrine only synchronizes the owning side (which is Position because ist has the VID column)

Comment: I do know what experts say, but you are persisting only the `entity` class in the db. So, if you check the entities after `remove` the entity it will show all null references because `$pos` and `$pos2` never was persisted

Comment: All entities have been inserted. That's the good part: I only need to flush $entity and through reachability $pos and $pos2 also get flushed. It is certain that before removing the relation all entites exist in their respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to persist the object that you want keep like this:

```
$pos->Vorgang = NULL;
$em->persist($pos2);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The view which showed the DB results after the script was inadequate. It now works as expected. The position is there.